# PHP MySQL - Cannot remove certain part of script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a strange problem.

Basically I have a page where a user can sign-up. The information is sent to a MySQL database where it will get stored. Before any work is done on the page I want a short script to change if the table already exist. If it doesn't exist it will get created, if it does exist continue to the next task.

For some reason, however, I receive an error if I remove the part "report result" (see the script below). The reason I want to remove it is basically because the user doesn't need to know that a table just was created.

Why can't I remove this part without getting an error?

```
<?php

$table       =     "database";

$servername      =  "xxx";
$username    =  "xxx";
$password    =  "xxx";
$dbname              =  "xxx";

// Connect to database
$conn = new mysqli($xxx, $xxx, $xxx, $xxx);

// Create table if it does not exist
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        example-1VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        example-2 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        example-3 VARCHAR(50),
        example-4 VARCHAR(50),
        example-5 VARCHAR(50),
        reg_date TIMESTAMP
        )";

// Report result <---------------------- PROBLEM HERE
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

// Insert data into table
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $example-1      =   $_POST['example-1'];
    $example-2      =   $_POST['example-2'];
    $example-3      =   $_POST['example-3'];
    $example-4      =   $_POST['example-4'];
    $example-5      =   $_POST['example-5'];

    // Check if already exist in table
    $query = "SELECT * from $table where email ='$example-3'";

    if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$query))

        {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            // If already exist in table
            echo "Already exists";

        } else

            // If doesn't exist, add to table
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (example-1, example-2, example-3, example-4, example-5)
            VALUES ('".$example-1."', '".$example-2."', '".$example-3."', '".$example-4."', '".$example-5."')";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            }

        } else

        // If everything fails for technical reason 
        echo "Query Failed.";

}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: `$example-2`, etc. are invalid variable names. What error are you receiving? You also are open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While removing the "Report result" block you must keep at least this part: `$conn->query($sql);`. Otherwise the table is not created at all..

And as per @chris85 comment the variable name must not contain minus `-` see      [PHP Manual Language Reference Variables Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Statement `$example-2` performs mathematical operation as `$example minus two`, so if `$example = 5` then result is `3`. This is what you do not want.

Better variable name would be `$example_2` or `$example2`

Comment: Thanx guys! The main problem was that I didn't know one has to use $conn->query($sql); ... I'm new at this... Everything works fine now, thanx again!